# delegation vs consultation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

can somebody explain me what is the difference between those two terms, found some information here http://javalab.cs.uni-bonn.de/research/darwin/delegation.html but can't understand

Comment: Which part(s) of that article are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: examples a little bit confusing, can You give me another example?

Comment: Link appears to be broken (now?).